# Magento API Error: "Procedure 'loginParam' not present"

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I had an issue come up with my Magento API calls. They were suddenly returning a SOAP fault where they were previously working just fine.

```
SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Procedure 'loginParam' not present
```

Also related: [Magento SOAP 2 API Fatal error: Procedure 'login' not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425909/magento-soap-2-api-fatal-error-procedure-login-not-present)

This above link what what clued me it - the object to string conversion error was being produced by my script in addition to the SOAP fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a very simple fix. Someone who had access turned off the "WS-I Compliance" in System > Config > Magento Core API and the "login" method expected a string instead of an object.

Now - to figure out which colleague did it... ;)

Comment: After i turned off still i am getting the error, can you pls help me to find out the error? @dgig

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to keep t he WS-I compliance and make it work, try to clear the cache.

More info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115257/747834