# Axis: createCall with params

Tags: java, magento, soap, wsdl, axis

I generated java code with [wsdl2java](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html) based on Magento WSDL (http://host/api?wsdl), but cannot call any procedure with params

**Environment:**

- JDK 1.8
- AXIS 1.4
- php 5.6
- Magento 1.6

**Problem:**

For example, [product.info](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html) api method required 2 params: `sessionId` and `productId`

code:

```
MagentoService magentoService = new MagentoServiceLocator();
Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBindingStub service = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBindingStub(new URL("http://myhost/api"), magentoService);

String sessionId = service.login("api-user", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

Call serviceCall = service.createCall();
serviceCall.setOperationName(new QName("call"));
serviceCall.setTargetEndpointAddress(new URL("http://myhost/api"));
serviceCall.addParameter("sessionId", Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
serviceCall.addParameter("resourcePath", Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
serviceCall.addParameter("productId", Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
serviceCall.setReturnType(Constants.SOAP_MAP);
serviceCall.invoke("call", new Object[] {sessionId, "product.info", new Object[]{2115}});
```

i checked database, product really exists. no matter which id used, i getting error:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: 101
 faultString: Product not exists.
```

i try another api methods, like a [customer.info](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html) and have the same result.

how to pass parameters correctly?

**What i did:**

- [disable wsdl cache on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115257/1511077)
- [clean wsdl cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115257/1511077)
- restart web services

Answer (score 3):

The Magento documentation has a mistake:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

The parameter "productId" should be replaced with "product".

Comment: Thanks for your response, but anyway product not found (same error)
i tried different ID's and SKU, but it doesn't work. Many people write that Magento SOAP is very buggy.

Comment: Yeah, I used it my self back in the days. There is a reason I do not use it anymore ^^